# C++ and QT thread extern variable not working

Tags: c++, qt, unresolved-external

I am writing a C++ program and I'm using QT for the GUI. I need to pass data from a QT thread to another, so I decided to use an external variable but it does not work. This is my code:

stream_buffer.h

```
#ifndef STREAM_BUFFER_H
#define STREAM_BUFFER_H

#include "opencv2/core.hpp"

extern cv::Mat frame_buffer;

#endif // STREAM_BUFFER_H
```

Thread1.cpp

```
#include "stream_buffer.h"

//Some code

cv::Mat frame_buffer;

video_stream >> frame_buffer;

//other code
```

Thread2.cpp

```
#include "stream_buffer.h

imshow("debug", frame_buffer);
```

During the compilation, I get the error `unresolved external symbol frame_buffer in function void run in Thread2.cpp`. If I define the `frame_buffer` variable also in Thread2.cpp it compiles but of course it does not work (since it is a local variable so it doesn't read the value from the common header file).

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: `extern cv::Mat frame_buffer;` is a declaration only. Where is this global variable defined?

Comment: In `Thread1.ccp`, there is the line `cv::Mat frame_buffer;`. Do I have to put a value inside the variable?

Comment: Is the variable really fully global ? Is it not a local variable ? If local, it cannot work.
In general it is discouraged to use "extern" in C++ (except in a few specific cases), so my advise is rather to create a proper getter function to access it. However be very careful with concurrency when accessing a same variable from multiple threads.

Comment: @Alexandre yes, I think that it is fully global. I have declared the variable as `extern` within a header file. Then I have included this header inside the cpp files that will use the variable. In one of these 2 cpp files, I fill the variable, in the other I'll read it. While compiling, I get a linker error!

Comment: Do you have both threads in the same library ? i.e. could it be an "export" issue ?
Does it solve your issue if you put a getter function instead ? e.g. cv::Mat& getFrameBuffer(); in the header, and define the function in Thread1.cpp ? (this is not the best, a getter should rather be for local variables, so in declared in Thread2.h instead of in stream_buffer.h). But this test could help understanding what is wrong.

Comment: @Alexandre I've tried already with a getter function, but it does not work and I have to figure out why. At the moment, I've put everything I need inside a unique thread.